# set a variable once for the whole golang project

Tags: go

I need to have a variable `volume_path` for my project.

volume_path is set in .env file, so I have 2 definition for it:

```
.env
.env.testing
```

In my code, I will set the var to:

```
var Volume_path = os.Getenv("VOLUME_PATH")
```

I know how to do it to set this var in each file, but I would like to define it just once, and make it accesible for all the project, is it possible ?

Comment: Then simply have one "instance" of this variable, and refer to this single instance everywhere. What is the problem?

Comment: I started coding go 2 weeks ago :) I tried to define it in main.go and refer it in other package, but I can't import main module to access it

Comment: package main is importable only in special cases, put your variable in a non-main package and import that one.

Comment: Just a thought but is `os.Getenv("VOLUME_PATH")` really so long to write compared to importing a variable from another file?

Comment: It would have been cleaner to have a VolumePath var, but I have no central package other than main, so, I guess I will do it like that...

Comment: please put an answer with that, I think I will accept icza answer, but I will upvote yours, as this it what I will do

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a single variable, and refer to that single instance from everywhere you need it.

Note that you can't refer to identifiers defined in the `main` package from other packages. So if you have multiple packages, this variable must be in a non-`main` package. Put it in package `example`, have it start with an uppercase letter (so it is exported), and import the `example` package from other packages, and you can refer to it as `example.Volume_path`.

Also note that the `Volume_path` name is not idiomatic in Go, you should name it rather `VolumePath`.

`example.go`:

```
package example

var VolumePath = os.Getenv("VOLUME_PATH")
```

And in other packages:

```
import (
    "path/to/example"
    "fmt"
)

func something() {
    fmt.Println(example.VolumePath)
}
```

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Yes, package `main` is special in many ways. Don't try to learn the language by drawing conclusions regarding to it.